# Spanning subgraphs defined via $K_4$ matchings

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, perfect-matchings

I have by accident found an interesting kind of spanner of complete symmetric graphs $G(V,E)$ with weighted edges.
What I actually had planned was to implement an algorithm for calculating certain non-optimal edges of TSP instances, but due to a bug I had actually calculated the set $\lbrace a,b \rbrace$ of edges with the property that for $\forall c\in E\setminus\lbrace a,b\rbrace:\ \exists d\in E\setminus\lbrace a,b,c\rbrace\ $ s.t. $\ \omega_{ab}+\omega_{cd}\le\omega_{ac}+\omega_{bd}\,\land\,\omega_{ab}+\omega_{cd}\le\omega_{ad}+\omega_{bc}$, i.e. for *every* vertex $c$ that is not adjacent to such an edge we can find another non-adjacent vertex $d$ such that the edges $\lbrace a,b\rbrace$ and $\lbrace c,d\rbrace$ resemble the minimum weight perfect matching of the subgraph induced by vertices $a,b,c,d$

[image: Visualization of the K4 matching edges]

The resulting graph is "almost" biconnected and may serve as the basis for shape hulls or partitioning of point sets. *crossing* pairs of edges are colored blue and the other, two-optimal subset of edges is depicted in yellow.

> **Question:**
>
> have spanning subgraphs that are defined by the edges of certain $K_4$ matchings already been investigated, resp. can anything be said about their properties?

Comment: What do you mean by *spanner*?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I meant it to be an abbreviation for [spanning subgraph](https://www.edmath.org/MATtours/discrete/concepts/csubgr.html), i.e. a subgraph that contains all vertices of the original graph. If that abbreviation isn't appropriate I will replace it in an edit; any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest just calling it a spanning subgraph.